# how to get total of amount against person_number and some more columns in a single oracle SQL query and grand amount

Tags: sql, oracle

i have one table the query is like this

```
SELECT
    cost_center_name,
    person_number,
    person_full_name,
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(wfc_start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') start_date,
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(wfc_end_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') end_date,
    TO_CHAR(wfc_start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') start_date_hours,
    TO_CHAR(wfc_end_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') end_date_hours,
    pay_code_name,
    duration_dd_hh_mi_ss,
    wage_amount,
FROM
    XX_pay_type a
WHERE
    person_number IN (
        '102',
        '103'
    )
    AND pay_period_ending_date = '20-APR-2019'
```

the     duration_dd_hh_mi_ss,
 has values like 00:4:32:00
                 00:3:20:00

i want the sum(wage_amount) and sum(duration_dd_hh_mi_ss) from the sql query
against person_number
i also want grand_total (wage_amount)

sum(duration_dd_hh_mi_ss) will be in this case  00:7:52:00

i tried sum(wage_amount) over(partition by person_number)
but i cannot get the sum(duration_dd_hh_mi_ss) against the person_number and the grand(wage_total)

Comment: If `wfc_start_date` is a `DATE` column, then the expression `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(wfc_start_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')` can be simplified to `wfc_start_date`. **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `duration` is substraction of `end_date` and `start_date` then use substraction. Do not follow first step.

**1**

Otherwise use [to_dsinterval()](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals#interval). But to be able to use it we need to replace first `:` in `duration` with space, because `to_dsinterval` does not accept this parameter.

```
select regexp_replace('00:2:32:00', ':', ' ', 1, 1) from dual;  -->  00 2:32:00

select to_dsinterval(regexp_replace('00:2:32:00', ':', ' ', 1, 1)) from dual;
```

Now we have intervals which can be summed, with some effort. It is [not trivial, but possible](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2903). Strings cannot.

**2**

To get partial sums and grand totals in one query use aggregation with `cube`, `rollup` or `grouping sets`. Here is an example with `rollup`:

```
-- sample data
with t(center, id, name, duration, wage_amount) as (
  select 'C1', '102', 'Tim', '01:2:00:00',  80 from dual union all
  select 'C1', '102', 'Tim', '00:0:32:00',  70 from dual union all
  select 'C2', '102', 'Tim', '00:2:00:00', 100 from dual union all
  select 'C2', '103', 'Bob', '00:2:00:00', 120 from dual )
-- end of sample data
```

query:

```
select center, id, name, sum(wage_amount) amt, 
       numtodsinterval(sum(sysdate + to_dsinterval(regexp_replace(duration, ':', ' ', 1, 1)) 
                           - sysdate ), 'day') duration
  from t
  group by rollup((id, name), center)
```

Result:

```
CENTER ID  NAME        AMT DURATION
------ --- ---- ---------- -------------------
C1     102 Tim         150 +000000001 02:32:00
C2     102 Tim         100 +000000000 02:00:00
       102 Tim         250 +000000001 04:32:00
C2     103 Bob         120 +000000000 02:00:00
       103 Bob         120 +000000000 02:00:00
                       370 +000000001 06:32:00
```

You can also do it as you started, using analytical sums which will give you values in additional columns. Or make a union (`union all`) of your data and grouping query.

Comment: in the above query

Comment: numtodsinterval(sum(sysdate + to_dsinterval(regexp_replace(duration, ':', ' ', 1, 1)) 
                           - sysdate ), 'day') duration

Comment: it gives the duration as +03 08:00:00.000000 I want it to be just in Hours and minutes

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of '`duration_dd_hh_mi_ss`' column?

Comment: DURATION_DD_HH_MI_SS             VARCHAR2(50) 

I want the sum(DURATION_DD_HH_MI_SS  ) by person_number
duration has the value

00:00:40:00,
00:03:00:00,
00:05:10:00
days:hours:minutes:seconds
here it will be 00:8:50:00